# Removing the dotted circle from Indic vowel signs

Tags: windows, unicode, indic, bengali

In windows 10, combining NSBP with Bengali vowel signs to remove the dotted circle doesn't seem to work. I tried with different fonts and even with Devanagari vowel signs. But none of them could omit the dotted circle. It works for android though. Is this a kind of bug in windows 10? What is the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour].  Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: It could be a bug but probably specific t certain text controls, not all of Windows. These sequences display for me without dotted circles in Edge as I enter comments in an input element:  া ূ ো. Where are you seeing NBSP + vowel signs display with a dotted circle?

Comment: Its in my PC, windows 10 installed and putting the input with NBSP before it in MS office and other programs doesn't omit the circle.